# Remove rating box from category page(RESOLVED)

Tags: product, ratings

I have try to remove rating box in frontend category listing but i have no idea. Someone can help ?

[image]

Comment: Please correct the category spelling

Comment: @Yasin2018 I'm very very interested in your products, can you please contact me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file ***app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\catalog\product\list.phtml*** and remove strings that echo Reviews information, for example:

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
```

Comment: hi i have delete but still tere

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this is use full for you

if you want remove rating in Product details page

go to you custom theme path

```
 app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

add below line

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
```

Next,

if you want remove rating in category page

go to you custom theme path

```
    app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

add below line

```
   <referenceContainer name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
```

remove var/* then check it.

Comment: hi thanks where ?  in the file

Comment: @Yasin2018  which file    catalog_product_view.xml or catalog_category_view.xml

Comment: ok understand but is dosnt matter i insert the line?

Comment: yes insert it, then remove var/*  check it.

Comment: The above won't work for category page, as the rating stars are being added directly within view.phtml without the layout name. Instead you may add an interceptor or do changes to template directly

Answer (score 0):

You neednt remove it or alter the source code, this is how you can disable the Customer Reviews or Rating from displaying in your product page.

The easiest way to disable / turn off features is to disable it at the "Disable Module Output" level. To do this, login to your Magento Admin Panel and go to System -> Configuration. Select Advanced from the left navigation select Disabled in the drop down for the Mage_Review module... Reload your page if needed after clearing cache, under cache management. Hope it helps, thank you.