# How to disable ratings & reviews in listing page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.0

I would like to disable **rating and reviews** link from category listing page. There is no option in admin system configuration. I couldn't find `referenceBlock` in `catalog_category_view.xml`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **Magento 2.2.0**, you have to remove this line from **list.phtml** file

```
<?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open file ***app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\template\catalog\product\list.phtml*** and remove strings that echo Reviews information, for example:

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
```

Copied from: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/135570/55042